Subscribing to a Question
I apologise if this has been asked previously elsewhere, but is there currently / could there be any facility to subscribe to a question?
I frequently find questions that are very interesting, and I would like to see others answers to them (though I have nothing to contribute myself). 

You can subscribe to updates of a question by adding it to your favorites. Just press the  button with the Star under the question's upvote and downvote arrows.
